# jquery prepend to a div html file content

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint, prepend

How to do this

```
$('#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight').prepend(load('~/_layouts/1033/nav.html'));
```

Something like this instead of :

```
$('#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight').prepend('<div style="padding-bottom:3px;background:#fff; color:white!important; float:left; margin-right:20px; line-height:40px;"><a style="padding:0 20px; border:1 green solid;" href="#">Sitemap</a> <a style="padding:0 20px; border:1 green solid;" href="#">Help</a><a style="padding:0 20px; border:1 green solid;" href="#">Welcome!</a></div>');
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the function .load()

like this

```
$('#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight').load('/_layouts/1033/nav.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("../_layouts/1033/nav.html", function(r){
    $("#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight").append(r);
});
```

This will not replace and execute script if required.